# Stored procedure not found when it exists

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have been looking for an answer on here and ca not seem to find  solution to my issue. I am running mysql on a mac and am having trouble calling a stored procedure. I see the procedure in the schema so I know it is there but when I try to call it in terminal or in the workbench is gives me "ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'zoo.insert_customer' doesn't exist".

Stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_customer (p_customer_id varchar(20)
,p_customer_fname varchar(20),p_customer_lname varchar(20),p_email 
varchar(20),p_address varchar(20),p_credit_card_info varchar(20))
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO insert_customer (customer_id,customer_fname, customer_lname, email, 
address, credit_card_info) VALUES(p_customer_id,p_customer_fname 
,p_customer_lname,p_email,p_address,p_credit_card_info);
END
```

calling the procedure:

```
CALL insert_customer('AAA100','john','pual','fiadd@gmail.com','10 Molly 
Way','100100');
```

then this is where I get the error "ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'zoo.insert_customer' doesn't exist".

Comment: Your procedure name is identical to your table name - that's probably an issue. "Insert_Customer" sounds like a verb and an unusual name for a table.

Comment: yep that was it! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is your table name the same as your stored procedure name?